# Problem when I merge 2 images, png show background in white

Tags: php, image, join, merge, gd

I have this problem, when I merge 2 images, the image .png show with background, I tried to remove with imagecolortransparent() and another functions but not working. The image was created without background, but I think that when image is created by imagecreatefrompng(),automatically put background.

This is the code:

```
$dest = imagecreatefromjpeg("1.jpg");
    $src = imagecreatefrompng("2.png");
    
    imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 10, 10, 0, 0, 1000, 900, 50); 
    $white = imagecolorallocate($src, 255, 255, 255);
    imagecolortransparent($src, $white);
    imagejpeg($dest, "1.png");

    imagedestroy($dest);
    imagedestroy($src);
```

Thanks you very much!

[image_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdRiX.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I have never had any success with the `GD`-package for image-manipulation in PHP.  I have always used (with great success) the Imagick package.  Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed.
The solution was use this code:

```
imagecopy($imagen1, $imagen2, 180, 135, 0,0, 201, 201);
```

such as

```
imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 10, 10, 0, 0, 1000, 900, 50);
```

Hear the all code:

```
$rutaImagen1 = 'directory/azul-gris.jpg';
    $rutaImagen2 = 'directory/lobo_geometrico.png';
    // Crear instancias de imágenes
    $imagen1 = imagecreatefromjpeg($rutaImagen1);
    $imagen2 = imagecreatefrompng($rutaImagen2);

    //Procesar imagenes y guardarlas
    imagealphablending($imagen2, true);
    imagesavealpha($imagen2, true);
    imagecopy($imagen1, $imagen2, 180, 135, 0,0, 201, 201);
    imagepng($imagen1, 'prueba.png');
```